# How to find a number $aabb$ that is a perfect square?

Tags: summation, divisibility, factoring

The number $aabb$ is

$$1000a + 100a + 10b + b = $$
$$1100a + 11b = $$
$$11 (100a + b) $$

To be a perfect square, each factor must appear an even number of times. Then $(100a + b)$ must be a multiple of $11$, which in this case is achieved by making that $a + b = 11$.

So, the possibles $a$ and $b$ are $9$ and $2$, $8$ and $3$, $7$ and $4$, $6$ and $5$, or the opposite order. But I don't know how to continue, because I am looking for an analytical way and not trying all possibilities to see which works.

Comment: You've narrowed things down so much that just trying every possibility is quick enough. If you recall that a square cannot end in $2,3,7,8$, you narrow it down more. A square cannot be $\equiv 2\pmod{4}$ or $\equiv 3 \pmod{4}$. That leaves you … very few options.

Comment: Of course, 0000 is also a perfect square. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $b=11-a$, the number is
$$11(100a+11-a)=11^2(9a+1)$$
so $9a+1$ is a perfect square. Also, $9a+1<83$. $9a+1=m^2$ yields $9a=(m+1)(m-1)$ and $m<10$. Since $m+1$ and $m-1$ can not be both multiples of $3$, then $m$ is $8$.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite it as $11(99a+(a+b)) = 121(9a+1)$, and it becomes pretty clear just from the identity $(x+1)(x-1)=(x^2-1)$ that you want $a=7, b=4$, and indeed $7744 = 88^2$

Answer (score 0):

Note:
After working this out
for base 10,
I looked at general base $m$
and found,
as shown in the second half
of this answer,
that,
in base $m\ge 5$,
$a=m-3, b=4$
gives
$(m+1)^2(m-3)^2
$.
There may be other solutions,
but there is always this one.

I worked this out
in my head 
before writing anything down,
so I'll ignore the
previous answers that
probably do
the exact same thing.

$aabb = 1000a+100a+10b+b
=1100a+11b
=11(100a+b)
$.

For this to be a square,
it must be of the form
$11^2n^2$,
so
$100a+b = 11n^2
$.

Since,
mod 11,
$100 = 99+1
= 1
$,
$a+b = 0$.
Since
$0 \le a, b \le 9$,
and ignoring the answer
$a = b = 0$,
we must have
$a+b = 11$
so
$b = 11-a$.

We must therefore have
$100a+(11-a)
=11n^2
$
or
$9a+1 = n^2$
or
$9a = n^2-1
=(n+1)(n-1)
$.
Since $a \le 9$,
$n \le 9$.

$n+1$ and $n-1$
can not be both divisible
by the same odd number
so $n+1 = 9$
and $n = 8$.

This gives
$a = 7, b=4$
so the number is
$7744 = 11^2\,8^2$
which works.

Now I'll see what happens
in an arbitrary base
$m$,
doing as much
copy and paste
as I can.

$aabb = m^3a+m^2a+mb+b
=(m^3+m^2)a+(m+1)b
=(m+1)(m^2a+b)
$.

I'll assume that
$m+1$ is prime,
because lazy and messy.
Let $m+1 = p$.

For this to be a square,
it must be of the form
$p^2n^2$,
so
$m^2a+b = pn^2
$.

Since,
$\bmod p$,
$m^2 = (p-1)^2
= 1
$,
$a+b = 0$.
Since
$0 \le a, b \le m-1$,
and ignoring the answer
$a = b = 0$,
we must have
$a+b = p$
so
$b = p-a$.

We must therefore have
$m^2a+(m+1-a)
=(m+1)n^2
$
or
$(m^2-1)a+m+1 = (m+1)n^2$
or
$(m-1)a+1 = n^2$
or
$(m-1)a = n^2-1
=(n+1)(n-1)
$.
Since $a \le m-1$,
$n \le m-1$.

One solution to this is
$n+1 = m-1,
n-1 = a$
so
$n = m-2,
a = m-3,
b = m+1-a = 4
$,
which gives,
$m^2(m-3)+4
=(m+1)(m-2)^2
$
or

$\begin{array}\\
(m+1)(m-2)^2
&=m^2(m-3)+4\\
&=m^2(m+1-4)+4\\
&=m^2(m+1)-4(m^2-1)\\
&=m^2(m+1)-4(m+1)(m-1)\\
&=(m+1)(m^2-4m+4)\\
\end{array}
$

which works.

Note that,
in any base $m \ge 4$,
$(m-3)(m-3)44
= (m+1)^2(m-2)^2
$.